# What is the best way to make textures?

Tags: texturing, uv

What is the best way to make textures? Which way do you use? 
I think UV mapping is most popular but not easy.

Comment: Do you mean "make textures", or "apply textures"?

Comment: UV unwrap, bake ambient occlusion, texture in Photoshop, then touch up seams with the paint and blur tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of texture it is.

For a texture which looks mostly the same everywhere (e.g. a dirt texture), you can use *[Blended Box mapping](http://vimeo.com/42856095)*:

[image]

For a texture which has an obvious definition of what should go where (e.g. a head texture), you probably want to use UV coordinates.